# Two technologically different mailserver (Postfix / Exchange) for one domain

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, exchange, mx-record, microsoft-office-365

I have a couple of users on a Debain Postfix Mailserver. All is fine. Now we need to put some users to a hosted Exchange Server (Office 365).

Is it possible to configure the mailservers and DNS MX for one domain in that way, that if the user inbox is not on server1 the lookup is forwarded to server2?

- What is the best practice for that?
- Who is the sending smtp?

Thanks Peter

Comment: You might want to change "technical" to "technologically"

Comment: What you're really looking for is using a shared SMTP namespace. Here's how to do it in Exchange, assuming that you can do the same in O365 - https://exchangeserverpro.com/how-to-share-an-email-domain-between-two-mail-systems

Comment: thx @joequerty. This is a good advice. I will test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well.... no and yes.

The problem is that when the DNS MX record lookup is done, the DNS server doesn't know who the user is (that information isn't sent to the DNS server), so the DNS server can not send MX records that are special for some users.  It would be weird (the technical phrase is "a layering violation") for the DNS to know so much about your users. Also, what if the email had 2 people on the `To:` line, one was for one of the original users and another for the Exchange users?  It gets confusing.

Let's call the users that have their email delivered on the Postfix server "Group P" and the users that want their email delivered on Exchange "Group E".

The solution is for the Postfix server to delivery Group P emails locally and forward Group E's emails to the Exchange server.  Likewise, the Exchange servers need to know to deliver Group E's emails locally and Group P's emails need to be forwarded.

The key is to make sure these two servers have the exact same information. Otherwise both servers will deliver a person's messages locally, or (even worse) neither will think they are responsible for the email and it will ping-pong back and forth between the servers.

### Solution if Group E is small:

If Group E is short (i.e. just a few exceptions), you can do this:

- On Postfix, set up aliases for each user to forward their email to their exchange account.
- On Exchange, configure the server to forward email for unknown users to the Postfix server. (Sadly I don't know the settings for this as I don't know Exchange).

### Solution for larger sites:

For larger configurations, I recommend that the two servers (call them serverE.example.com and serverP.example.com) are configured to deliver local email for user@serverE.example.com and user@serverP.example.com respectively, but not deliver email locally for user@example.com.  Each machine accesses an LDAP/ActiceDirectory database that indicates that (for example) tom@example.com has his email delivered to tom@serverP.example.com and geri@example.com has her email delivered to geri@serverE.example.com.  This way things stay in sync and you only have one place to update.

Little known fact: With postfix, if the `aliases` file contains:

```
tom: tom@serverP.example.com
geri: geri@serverE.example.com
```

And mail.cf's mydestination contains `serverP.example.com` but not `serverE.example.com`, then mail to `tom` will be delivered locally and mail to `geri` will be relayed to serverE.  It won't create a loop!

I raise this issue because before I knew this, I wrote a big perl script that generated `aliases` files for each mail server so that (for example) `tom` didn't appear in the `aliases` file for `serverP`, just all the others.  Once I knew this, I eliminated the script. The exact same `aliases` file could be on all machines. (Of course, since Exchange doesn't use `aliases` files, something else must be done on those servers.)

If `myorigin = example.com` then outgoing email will have "tom@example.com" in the `From:` line, and nobody will be the wiser that there are two email servers.  (I don't know the Exchange equivalent, but I'm sure it exists.)

### Testing advice

When testing this configuration, don't just test if incoming email goes to the right place.  Also make sure that email sent from each client goes to the right place.  For example have an Exchange user send a message `To: tom, geri` and make sure both get delivered.  Have Debian user do the same.  I've seen situations where (for example) the aliases and/or forward wasn't set up right on both machines and emails were getting delivered locally for user `tom` on both servers.  `tom` had to read email in both places until this was fixed.  Oops!

Comment: Thank you so much for your very good explanation. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have Postfix receive all mail, and then forward it off to the Exchange server based on rules/aliases, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few users in postfix, it will probably be easier to create Mail Contacts in Exchange, and put the postfix users on an internal sub domain.

Do you want to accomplish anything in particular, like routing mail through Exchange Online Protection?

Best Practice is that you will have only one service in your MX record, and the second service will need to be authorized to send mail through the primary (a Connector in Exchange parlance)

You can send SMTP through both services **if** you configure SPF for both services to send on behalf of your mail domain.

Answer (score 0):

Like these other users have said, this is what is known as a SMTP namespace sharing. You mention couple of users on the Postfix system. I would have all email sent to the Exchange server and then handoff the email of the unknown users to the Postfix system. Look under the Default SMTP Properties. You will need to look for something that says "Forward all mail with unresolved recipients to host:".